# Recognize if language is Japanese BUT verify if quantity of chars from other languages

Tags: javascript, php, regex

Seems a bit complicated my request but I think the idea is:

I want to check a string and consider if is Japanese or not... but based in the quantity of Japanese characters in the string (Hiragana, Katakana or Kanji).

Example:

```
> "Hi Johnさん, thank you very much." -> Show as Non Japanese
> "ジョン様、ありがとうございました。"   -> Show as Japanese "John-san,ありがとうございました！"   ->
> Show as Japanese "John-san, Thank you very much! すごいね！"  -> Show as
> Non Japanese
```

For the case I use now it automatically considers Japanese if contains only one Kanji/Hiragana/Katakana char, by checking using regex with preg_match.
Any ideas how I would check a text with roman+Japanese (or asian chars) and define the language considering the one that has more?

I might also apply the same idea for Chinese and Korean too.

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: Language guessing using a regex? I doubt it is a good idea. There are NLP packages for that.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't think use regex for language guessing is good. I made a function to recognize based in a word dictionary for each language, but I would like to be more precise (considering the example I show above).

Comment: So, what is a problem? Just use a regex to match a Japanese char, and a regex to match ASCII letters. Then check their lengths.